# Can MoveIt create plans for future move group states?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working to optimize the cycle time of a repeated set of arm movements. We're using MoveIt to plan and execute trajectories in C++. It can take up to half a second to plan and optimize a trajectory using the MoveGroupInterface::plan function and I'd like to parallelize this since the start state of the next move is known ahead of time if the current move is successful.

Is it possible to specify a start joint state and request a plan from that start state to an end state/pose, and if so how is this done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316233/can-moveit-create-plans-for-future-move-group-states?/) by [ssnover](https://answers.ros.org/users/39852/ssnover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can.
You can either plan for a specific joint state([link to plan struct](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/structmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup_1_1Plan.html)) as a start state.
Or if the trajectory is always the same - you can just save your plan.
But seems like specifying start joint state solves your problem

---

Originally posted by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) with karma: 76 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1